# Indicar se a posição está antes ou depois de uma lista (python)

Tags: python

Preciso fazer um programa que indica se expressões matemáticas estão corretas por meio da quantidade e posição dos parênteses.

Mas eu queria saber se tem alguma forma indicar se o `')'` está em uma posição antes de `'('`...
tipo se `')'` estiver antes de `'('`:

```
while True:
    lista= list(str(input('digite uma expressão: ')))

    aberto = lista.count('(')
    fechado = lista.count(')')

    if aberto == fechado:
        print('A expressão está correta.')
    elif aberto != fechado:
        print('A expressão está incorreta.')
    
    res = str(input('Deseja informar outra expressão?'))
    while res.capitalize().strip()[0] != 'S'and res.capitalize().strip()[0] != 'N':
        res = str(input('Resposta inválida'))
    if res.capitalize().strip()[0] == 'N':
        break
```

Comment: Usar `str.index()` para retornar a posição dos elementos, então comparar os índices de `aberto` e `fechado` para validar a expressão, não resolveria?

Answer (score -2):

Para esta verificacao teria que ser criada duas listas com as posicoes dos parenteses para verificar cada posicao do parenteses fechado com o parenteses aberto.

Caso a posicao for menor, ele esta antes. Pode usar o metodo index() conforme o Cmte Cardeal informou acima.

Segue o codigo abaixo que faz o que voce precisa:

```
expressao = input("Insira uma expressao: ")

"""Transforma expressao em lista"""
list_expressao = list(expressao)

parenteses = ['(',')']

found = []

"""Adiciona apenas os parenteses da expressao na lista vazia found"""
for letter in list_expressao:
    if letter in parenteses:
        found.append(letter)

i = 0
j = 0

"""Separa os parenteses abertos e fechados em duas listas distintas"""
parenteses_aberto = []
parenteses_fechado = []


"""Adiciona as posicoes dos parenteses as suas devidas listas"""
for letter in found:
    if letter == '(':
        parenteses_aberto.append(found.index(letter)) 
        found.remove(letter)
        found.insert(0,0)

        
    elif letter == ')':
        parenteses_fechado.append(found.index(letter))
        found.remove(letter)
        found.insert(0,0)

"""OBS: metodo index() nao encontra valor duplicado, por isso temos que
        remover e adicionar o valor 0 no lugar do parenteses"""

ultimo_elemento = len(parenteses_aberto)


"""Compara as posicoes dos parenteses fechados na sua lista, com as posicoes dos
parenteses abertos. Se a posicao for menor, indica que esta antes."""
for letter in parenteses_fechado:
    while j != ultimo_elemento:
        if parenteses_fechado[i] < parenteses_aberto[j]:
            print('{}o parenteses fechado antes do {}o parenteses aberto'.format(i+1,j+1), '\t')
            j = j+1
        else:
            j = j+1
    i = i+1
    j = 0
```